# Orthonormal functions as a combination of three complex functions

Tags: operator-theory, orthonormal

I have some problem to find three orthonormal functions in the interval $-1\le x\le 1$ as a linear combination of these three functions:
$$f_1(x)=1,f_2(x)=x\exp(i\pi x),f_3(x)=\exp(i\pi x)$$
Is it possible to use the Gram - Schmidt method?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Not only it is possible to use G'S, but methodically there probably is not another method that works in the general case. The problem here is that you didn's say what the inner product here is...

Comment: @DonAntonio: I don't know much about G-S's method, but is there any relation between Orthogonality and Independence of set of some finite functions on an interval $I$? I see there is. Am I right? Thanks.

Comment: @Don Antonio: what inner product I should define?

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra, the one giving the exercise (an instructor, a book, etc.) *must* give an inner product on the vector space, otherwise how are you supposed to know when soome vectors are orthonormal, orthogonal, etc.?

Comment: @BabakS., a set of non-zero pairwise orthogonal vectors is linearly independent, so if you check this on a finite set of functions on some interval wrt some appropiate inner product then yes: you are right.

Comment: The inner product is the usual inner product defined in $L^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Gram-Schmidt process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process), as correctly pointed out in the comments, you will notice that, in order to get three orthogonal functions in $L^2$ with the inner product $\langle f_i,f_j\rangle=\int_{-1}^1dxf_i^*(x)f_j(x)$, it is enough to rewrite
$$
   f_2(x)=xe^{i\pi x}-\frac{i}{\pi}.
$$
Then you can properly normalize them.